# Length of Piecewise Linear Curve avoiding N points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, computational-geometry, arc-length

Let $y_0,y_1,x_1,\dots,x_N$ be distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Clearly there exists a piecewise linear curve $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ joining $y_0$ to $y_1$ for which
$$
\min_{t \in [0,1]}\,\|\gamma(t) - x_i\|>\delta 
\quad \text{where} \quad  
\delta < \min \{ \min_{i\neq j}\frac{\|x_i-x_j\|}{2},\min_{1≤j≤N\\i=0,1} \|y_i-x_j\|\} \,.
$$

What is the infimum of the length of such a curves?

Comment: I think you mean $\min_{t\in [0,1]}$ instead of $\max$, otherwise the condition is trivially satisfied as long as $y_0$ or $y_1$ is sufficiently far from $x_i$.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that Rahul.

Comment: Here $\|.\|$ denotes the Euclidean distance ?

Comment: In its current form, it is not clear what your question is asking. Do you mean given a $\delta$ smaller than the separation among the $N$ points $x_1,\ldots, x_N$. What is the minimum length of a piecewise linear curve joining $y_0$ and $y_1$ which is disjoint from the $N$ closed balls of radius $\delta$ centered at $x_k$. BTW, if $\|\cdots\|$ stand for Euclidean norm, the minimum need not exists as the shortest curve disjoint from the open balls may consists of circular arcs on the surface of the balls.

Comment: I doubt there is a nice formula for this, in part, because it depends on the precise configuration $x_1,...,x_N$. One way to estimate the length is to draw a straight-line path from $y_0$ to $y_1$. Whenever this path enters a ball $B(x_i, \delta)$, reroute the path along the boundary of $B(x_i, \delta)$. (This will result in a path satisfying nonstrict inequalities.) However, I do not see a reason for this path to be the shortest.

Comment: I have a suspicion that this problem (with $\min$ replaced by $\inf$, as achille hui suggested) is an $NP$-hard problem in computational geometry.

Comment: I don't think the question text captures the intended problem correctly. Consider regular two-dimensional Euclidean plane and place four points $\{x_1,\ldots,4\}=\{(\pm 2,\pm 2)\}$. Then, set $\delta=3$ and look for path connecting $y_0=(0,0)$ and $y_1=(6,0)$. Since $y_0$ lies inside a square with corners in $x_i$ and $y_1$ is outside, any path must cross the boundary of the square. But every point of the boundary is at distance at most $2$ from some corner. Thus, there is no such connecting path at all, contradicting the "Clearly there exists..." part of the problem statement.

Comment: [cont] Of course, we can guarantee the existence of such path by requiring $\delta < \frac{1}{2}\min_{i\neq j}\|x_i-x_j\|$ but doing so would imply the path can wiggle between between any pair of points $x_i$, $x_j$. Is that the intended interpretation?

Comment: @AlexRavsky  I expect that it is, in some form, equivalent to the problem of finding graph geodesics:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03868.pdf

Comment: @PeterKošinár I modified OP's question accordingly

Comment: @PeterKošinár Yes this is the intention, infact it's the goal.

Comment: "Minimum length of such a curve" should be replaced by "infimum of lengths of such curves."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Fair enough, I made the suggested edit.... I get the feeling that this question is non-trivial somehow....

Comment: @MrMMS: Most likely, there is nothing like a "formula" for this infimum. What one can easily get is an estimate 
 $||y_0-y_1||\le L\le \frac{\pi}{2}||y_0-y_1||$, which will suffice for practical applications.

Comment: Sorry...where does the $\pi$ come from?  I'd accept this as an answer with some more details :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an elaboration on my comments.

I do not think there are anything like a nice "closed" formula for the infimum $L$ of length such paths. However, one can estimate $L$ as follows. 
I will assume that ${\mathbb R}^n$ is equipped with the Euclidean metric $d=||x-y||$, making it a Euclidean space $E^n$.

Let $p, q\in E^n$ be points in 
$$
U=E^n - \bigcup_{i=1}^N B(x_i, \delta). 
$$
Connect $p$ to $q$ by the Euclidean line segment $pq$ (of length $d(p,q)$, of course). This path need not be contained in $U$, so we modify it as follows. 
Whenever $pq$ crosses a ball $B(x_i,\delta)$  along a segment $p_iq_i$, we replace this subsegment of $pq$ with the shortest arc $\widehat{p_iq_i}$ of a great circle on the boundary sphere of $B(x_i,\delta)$. Let $c_{pq}$ denote the new path from $p$ to $q$. It lies outside of the union of open balls $B(x_i,\delta)$.

The length of the arc $\widehat{p_iq_i}$ equals $2\delta\alpha_i$, where $\alpha_i$ is the angle $\frac{1}{2}\angle p_i x_i q_i$. Denoting $D_i$ the length of the chord $p_iq_i$, and doing some trigonometry observe that 
$$
\frac{2\delta\alpha}{D_i}= \frac{2\alpha}{\sin \alpha_i}=f(\alpha_i). 
$$
The function $f(\alpha)= \frac{2\alpha}{\sin \alpha}$ has no critical points on the open interval $(0,\pi/2)$, so its maximum is realized when $p_iq_i$ is the diameter, i.e.
$$
\frac{2\delta\alpha_i}{D_i} \le \frac{\pi}{2}.   
$$
Therefore, replacing the chords $p_iq_i$ with the arcs $\widehat{p_i q_i}$ throughout $pq$ can increased the overall length at most by the factor $\pi/2$. I am not claiming that the path $c_{pq}$ I constructed is the shortest path from $p$ to $q$ which avoids all the open balls $B(x_i,\delta)$: In many cases it is not.

To conclude: The minimal length $L$ of a path from $p$ to $q$ in the complement to the open balls $B(x_i,\delta)$ satisfies 
$$
d(p,q)\le L\le \frac{\pi}{2} d(p,q) \le 1.6 d(p,q). 
$$

To be off by a linear factor is not too bad for this type of problems.

Incidentally, finding a path from $p$ to $q$ in a more general setting (when obstacles overlap and their location and shapes are a priori unknown) is an interesting problem in autonomous robot navigation. (Think of a GPS-equipped Roomba robot trying to get from one room to another.) There is a general "ellipse method"  for solving this in the plane due to Lumelsky. From what I remember, his solution is off by a uniform multiplicative factor from an optimal solution. The situation in dimension 3 (and higher) is far from clear. However, I am not an expert in this staff.

Comment: Thank you Moishe.  Also, I was unaware of the related literature on autonomous robot navigation and the ellipse method.  I'll have to read up on this!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Might as well consider the relaxed condition $\min\|\gamma(t) - x_i\|\ge \delta$, since the infimum of the lengths will be the same. The advantage is that now we do have optimal paths, since their image lies in a closed set.

The problem is to find the shortest path between two points that avoids a family of (open) disks.  Intuitively, we understand what these path look like in some simple cases. They must consist of some pieces of tangents to the circles and some arcs.  For instance, in the case of one disk,  the shortest path  consist of a tangent from $y_0$ to the disk, then an ark, then completed with a tangent from $y_1$ to the disk.

In any homotopy class of paths from $y_0$ to $y_1$ that avoid the (open) disks there is a unique shortest path. This is like tightening a rope around some trees.

Comment: In fact, uniqueness (in the given relative homotopy class) is true only in dimension 2 (and the proof I know is nonelementary). But uniqueness fails in dimensions $\ge 3$ (for the same reason that minimal geodesics on spheres are non-unique).

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks but I can prove its existence with homological arguments; very easy infact.  But I want an analytic bound (that's the difficult part).